# Flash msg optional param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I pass an optional parameter to the flash message?

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap alert messages, and I want to add the ".alert-block" css class to the message, based on a parameter or something I set in the controller.

Thanks.

---

This is my solution:

```
flash[:success_block] = "<h4>Bla blah.</h4> <p>Blah blah.</p>"



<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>

  <% block = true if name.to_s.split('_').last == 'block' %>
  <% name = name.to_s.split('_').first if block %>

  <div class="alert fade in alert-<%= name %> <%= 'alert-block' if block %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <%= msg.html_safe %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to map the flash message on the different alert types that twitter bootstrap provides (ie flash[:info] to .alert-info, flash[:success to alert-success]...)

You can't pass parameters to flash variables, but you can access instance variables of a controller, or even methods by using helper_method from your views/layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the info that I can't pass parameters to flash variables.